# How to call an UIControl callback function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

In my MATLAB application, i've a callback function associated with a toggle button, let's say `tg_callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)`, which is called in a script, let's say *callee.m*. However, when MATLAB tries to execute this function, i get the following error:

> Undefined function 'tg_callback' for input arguments of type 'matlab.ui.control.UIControl'.

The callback function is defined in another script, let's say *caller.m*, which also calls the script *callee.m*. In addition, the application was developped with MATLAB R2007 and i must upgrade its code for MATLAB R2022. The GUI was made the MATLAB GUIDE tool.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Does this error also occur with the 2007 version? What changes did you make? Can you provide a [mre] of the actual function definition, where it is assigned to the button callback, and where you’re trying to call it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i resolved this problem. The reason was that the callback function was defined in a script whose name was different than the name of the callback. So, i can't use it outside of this script. I move the callback into its own script and now, i can call it anywhere in my code.